# Popup screen not working on Android, but does on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator

I'm trying to create an popup that contains help information. The below code works perfect on iOS, but on Android the labels aren't displayed (the close button is).

I'm hoping there is an easy fix ;-)

Thanks in advance!

```
function helpPopup() {


var myModal = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    navBarHidden:true
});



var wrapperView    = Ti.UI.createView(); // Full screen
var backgroundView = Ti.UI.createView({  // Also full screen
    backgroundColor : '#000',
    opacity         : 0.5
});
backgroundView.addEventListener('click', function () {
    myModal.close();
});
var containerView  = Ti.UI.createView({  // Set height appropriately
    height          : 300,
    backgroundColor : '#FFF'
});
var someLabel      = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text    : 'Here is your modal',
    top     : 40
});

var contactName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text    :'Name',
    top     :60
});

var closeButton    = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title  : 'Close',
    bottom : 40
});
closeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    myModal.close();
});


containerView.add(someLabel);
containerView.add(contactName);
containerView.add(closeButton);

wrapperView.add(backgroundView);
wrapperView.add(containerView);


myModal.add(wrapperView);

myModal.open({
    animate : true
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Android uses white as a default label color.... iOS uses black.

So after I changed the font color it worked on both Android on iOS:

var someLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
text : 'Here is your modal',
top : 40,
color : '#000'
});